# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() in Model,fit()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying image to image mapping. i had to create a custom datagenerator as the imagedatagenerator gives **`y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input. error**.I found this datagenerator created by someone else and modified it to fit my need. And now again i am getting this error. I dont know why i am getting this error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
class image_gen():
    def __init__(self, sdir, batch_size,input_size, shuffle):          
        self.batch_index=0  
        self.sdir=sdir # directory containing input images
        self.batch_size=batch_size   #batch size is number of samples in a batch
          # tuple (width, height)  for target image 
        self.input_size=input_size   
        self.shuffle=shuffle   # set to True to shuffle images, False for no shuffle
        self.label_list=[] # initialize list to hold sequential list of total labels generated
        self.image_list=[] # initialize list to hold sequential list of total images filenames generated
        self.s_list=os.listdir(self.sdir)   # list of images in directory      
        
    def get_images(self):    # gets a batch of input images, resizes input image to make target images        
        input_image_batch=[] # initialize list to hold a batch of target images
         # initialize list to hold batches of  input images 
        sample_count=len(self.s_list)  # determine total number of images available         
        for i in range(self.batch_index * self.batch_size, (self.batch_index + 1) * self.batch_size  ): #iterate for  a batch
            j=i % sample_count # cycle j value over range of available  images
            k=j % self.batch_size  # cycle k value over batch size
            if self.shuffle: # if shuffle select a random integer between 0 and sample_count-1 to pick as the image=label pair
                m=np.random.randint(low=0, high=sample_count-1, size=None, dtype=int) 
            else:
                m=j   # no shuffle         
            path_to_img=os.path.join(self.sdir, self.s_list[m]) # define the path to the m th image 
            input_image=cv2.imread(path_to_img)
             #create the target image from the input image            
            input_image_batch.append(input_image)        
                    
        input_image_array=np.array(input_image_batch) 
        
        self.batch_index=self.batch_index +1         
        yield (input_image_array)
batch_size=32
target_shape=(3402,3401,)
sdir=r"D:Input\\train" # set this to your image directory
shuffle=False
gen=image_gen(sdir, batch_size,target_shape,shuffle) # instantiate an instance of the class
input_images=next(gen.get_images()) # get a batch of inputs, labels

batch_size=32
target_shape=(3402,3401,)
sdir=r"D:\\Validation\\valid" # set this to your image directory
shuffle=False
gen=image_gen(sdir, batch_size,target_shape,shuffle) # instantiate an instance of the class
Valid_images=next(gen.get_images()) # get a batch of inputs, labels

batch_size=32
target_shape=(3402,3401,)
sdir=r"D:\\Output\\train" # set this to your image directory
shuffle=False
gen=image_gen(sdir, batch_size,target_shape,shuffle) # instantiate an instance of the class
output_images=next(gen.get_images()) # get a batch of inputs, labels

base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(3402,3401,3),
    pooling=None,  
)
for layer in base_model.layers[:]:
    layer.trainable = False
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Convolution2D(3,9,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Convolution2D(3,9,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.build((None, 3402, 3401, 3))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
model.fit(input_images,output_images,validation_data = Valid_images,epochs=100)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-41ebbbad4a4a> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(input_images,output_images,validation_data = Valid_images,epochs=100)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1095               (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
   1096 
-> 1097     if validation_data:
   1098       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight = (
   1099           data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like model.fit expects a different type of argument for the `validation_data` parameter than what you are providing it.

The [Keras documentation on `model.fit`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) states:

> validation_data:
>
> Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of
> each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data.  Thus, note
> the fact that the validation loss of data provided using
> validation_split or validation_data is not affected by regularization
> layers like noise and dropout. validation_data will override
> validation_split.
>
> validation_data could be:
>
> - A tuple (x_val, y_val) of Numpy arrays or tensors.
> - A tuple (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) of NumPy arrays.
> - A tf.data.Dataset.
> - A Python generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs,     targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).

What is the type of your validation data when it goes into `model.fit()`?

Regarding the error message; if an `if variable:` statement is used and `variable` is a numpy array, whether this should evaluate to `True` is ambiguous.

For example:

```
arr = np.array([True, True, False])
if arr:
    ...
```

Should this evaluate to true?

```
arr = np.array([True, True, True])
if arr:
    ...
```

Or should it only evaluate to true if all elements do?

If one wants the former to evaluate to true, one could use `arr.any()`. If all elements are required to evaluate to True for the entire array to also be evaluated as such, `arr.all()` should be used.
When neither option is provided, an exception is raised.

Now this could be a bug in the keras module, but I think it is far more likely that `model.fit()` expects different input from what you are putting in.

Comment: So this is my understanding from your comment. The validation data should be A tuple (x_val, y_val) of Numpy arrays or tensors. I am trying end to end mapping of low resolution and high resolution. so that mean x_val should be lr and y_val should be hr. And they should be in numpy array. Correct? for the input i found the above code changes the shape for some reason that is why the error i guess

Comment: "I am trying end to end mapping of low resolution and high resolution. so that mean x_val should be lr and y_val should be hr."


I don't know whether `x_val` should be lr and `y_val` should be hr; I'm not very familiar with this domain yet. I do know that a tuple of two numpy arrays should solve this error; it seems like the error occurs when checking if validation data has been defined. So you may have passed a single numpy array instead of a tuple of two arrays?

It seems that `next(gen.get_images())` goes in as validation data, so  should return a tuple.

Comment: Yes i did not know that validation has to be tuple of two arrays.

Comment: Hope it helps you. By the way, if this answer has solved your question you could mark it as the 'accepted answer'.